# Loading PDF file with Imagick: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, php-7.2

I want to **convert the first page of a PDF** file into a JPEG image in order to display it on the website page.

I'm workink with:

- Apache2 ***v2.4.35***
- PHP ***v7.2.10***
- Extension ***php_imagick-3.4.3-7.2***
- ImageMagick ***v7.0.7-11***

When I load the entire file, there is no problem. But when I want to load the first page, an error appears:

> GET http://localhost/local.sfdp.org/actus.php?id=1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)

Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcfTP.png) of the error.

### My code:

```php
$fullPath = __DIR__ . '/documents/public/actualite/file.pdf'; // the path is good
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution(300,300);

$im->readimage($fullPath); // This works
// $im->readimage($fullPath.'[0]'); // This doesn't work

$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$im->writeImage(__DIR__ . '/documents/public/actualite/thumb.jpg');
```

Thanks in advance

### [EDIT]

I just discover something:
It works only for the 2nd page

```
$im->readimage($fullPath.'[0]'); // This doesn't work
$im->readimage($fullPath.'[1]'); // This works
$im->readimage($fullPath.'[2]'); // This doesn't work
```

Comment: Post your a link to you PDF file. It does not make sense that you can only access page [1]. Is your Imagick version compatible with Imagemagick 7? What version of Ghostscript is being used by Imagemagick?

Comment: It's really uncertain. I tried with others files and for the big majority, it doesn't work. Just in some cases it works for just some pages :/ So the problem is not the file, i guess.

Comment: Post a link to a file that fails. Also check your version of Ghostscript and report that here. I have heard of issues with GS 9.26, so perhaps if you have that back it down to 9.23 for example. If your PDF is CMYKA (with alpha), then GS does not handle that. You will need to convert to RGB. `convert -colorspace sRGB -density X image.pdf result.pdf` in command line format. You will have to find the equivalent in your API. "connection reset" sounds like a timeout to me. Is your PDF very large?

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET is an error which usually comes up when the site you are trying to visit cannot establish connection with the destination site. Your other sites may work, but certain sites won't. Are you trying to read a PDF via http protocol?